# HttpResponseMessage gets serialized in response

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a method that returns a HttpResponseMessage. So if the query is correct it returns a BadRequest, else 200OK.

I noticed that the query always came in the `success` method of my AJAX call. Even though I returned a BadRequest. After checking my network tab, I noticed some weird behavior. The general request is a 200OK, but the HttpResponseMessage was serialized in the body as JSON.

[image: Response]
[image: Body]

I don't really get why this happens. My code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Register([FromBody] RegisterPresentationModel register)
{
    if (register == null)
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            ReasonPhrase = "Value passed in request is null"
        };

    if (register.Password != register.ConfirmPassword)
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            ReasonPhrase = "Passwords do not match"
        };
    var user = new UserPassPresentationModel
    {
        Email = register.Email,
        UserName = register.UserName,
        Roles = new List<string> {ApplicationRoles.User},
        Password = register.Password,
        ConfirmPassword = register.ConfirmPassword
    };
    return await _userRepo.Add(user);
}
```

The AJAX call is this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/auth/",
    type: "post",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': "application/json"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(register),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        element.registerform.isValid = false;
        element.registerform.error = data.responseText;
    }
});
```

Comment: Well... why you return `HttpResponseMessage` from controller? Use `Ok()`, `BadRequest`, `Json` or even `ObjectResult` instead of this.

Comment: Yeah I now switched to using IActionResult and sending those values instead. Weird though because I swear HttpResponseMessage used to work!